# How do I deobfuscate this JavaScript?

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript

link to the code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y-M-gkYpzkrECh6gpsVyo_ZMO5ZMgdiW/view

I tried using this site (https://lelinhtinh.github.io/de4js/), but it still accomplishes almost nothing

youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJa18i8Xx9c

Comment: Might be worth trying a few different deobfuscators - this one does a decent job of decoding a lot of the strings: https://deobfuscate.relative.im/

Answer (score 1):

first use https://deobfuscate.relative.im/ to get the initial code, then there is a tool called [wakaru](https://wakaru.vercel.app/#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), and the logic is much clear now.

for example:

```js
      return (_0x5a593e) => {
        if (_0x5a593e + "" == _0x1f7284) {
          return window.mapDataLayoutBackup;
        }
        _0x1f7284 = _0x5a593e + "";
        if (typeof _0x5a593e == "string") {
          _0x5a593e = window.JSON.parse(_0x5a593e);
        }
        if (typeof _0x5a593e[0] == "number") {
          _0x5a593e = window.JSON.parse(window.LZMA.decompress(_0x5a593e));
        }
```

and

```js
    ["_0xb010e1"]: async function (_0x2b8c61) {
      await new window.Promise((_0x2731d0) => {
        return window.setTimeout(_0x2731d0, 150);
      });
      let _0x14c2d2 = window.location.href.match(/modes\/(\w+)\/c/)[1];
      let _0x6bd428 = (_0x3bbdc0) => {
        let _0x54f3d9 = window.document.createDocumentFragment();
        let _0x3c1c6b = window.document.createElement("div");
        for (_0x3c1c6b.innerHTML = _0x3bbdc0; _0x3c1c6b.firstChild; ) {
          _0x54f3d9.appendChild(_0x3c1c6b.firstChild);
        }
        window.document.body.insertBefore(
          _0x54f3d9,
          window.document.body.childNodes[0]
        );
      };
```